# ComboBox binding inside Item template with IEnumerable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, itemscontrol

I have one class ***MovieSystem*** which inherits from ***AvailableMovies*** collection.

```
public class MovieSystem  : IEnumerable<AvailableMovies >, IEnumerable
{
    public AvailableMovies this[int i] { get; }
    public AvailableMovies this[TheatreLocation location] { get; }
    public AvailableMovies [] ReleasedMovies { get; }
 }
```

TheatreLocation is an enum with values like

```
public enum TheatreLocation 
{
        Citycentre = 0,
        CityNorth = 1,
        CitySouth = 2,
        CityEast = 3,
        CityWest = 4,
}
```

AvailableMovies collection is with below properties

```
public class AvailableMovies 
{
        public AvailableMovies ();
        public int Index { get; }
        public TheatreLocation Location { get; set; }
        public string TheatreID { get; set; }
        public double Ticketprice{ get; }
}
```

My Xaml code looks like below

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MovieSystem  }">            
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path= ""What should I bind here? ""}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path = ???}"
                                      SelectedIndex="{Binding Path =Location , Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource MovieSystemLocationConverter}}">
                            </ComboBox>
                            <ComboBox
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path = ???}"
                                      SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=TheatreID , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path= ??}">
                            </ComboBox>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="3"
                                     Text="{Binding Path= Ticketprice, Mode =TwoWay,StringFormat=F3, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
                                    
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have a view model, xaml datacontext is set to this view model.

```
internal class MovieSystemPanelViewModel
{
        ///tried this collection but not worked.
        public ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel> Locations { get; } = new ObservableCollection<LocationViewModel>();
   
        public MovieSystem MovieSystem { get; }
              
        public MovieSystemPanelViewModel() {}
}
```

Now my problem is both ComboBox which should display Theatre id and location not displaying due to binding issue. If try to bind that Locations observable collection inside ComboBox itemsource its not allowing, inside items template only AvailableMovies properties are in bindable condition.
Ticketprice is binding properly and displaying.

Comment: So what is expected? You have an outer `ItemsControl` that displays an `AvailableMovies` object as item, so the data template has access to the `Index`, `Location`, ... properties, but those are not collections, so you cannot bind them them as an `ItemsSource`. What should those `ComboBox`es display? Why the outer `ItemsControl`? The only thing that should be working here is the `Ticketprice` `TextBox`.

Comment: Outer items control is mandatory to use as it has ticket price also maximum number available movies and other important properties are there to bind. Since that is binded I am not able to bind anything else inside ComboBox, only option I tried and worked is hardcoded Content in ComboBox and removing item source and display member path , But is there any way I can make it dynamic without hardcoded enum values in content?

Comment: Ok, but that does not explain what the `ComboBox`es should be bound to. What should the `ComboBox` with selected index `Location` be bound to? Where is the collection for that? Do you want to display the enum values? Then what does the `MovieSystemLocationConverter` do and what is `LocationViewModel`? The same goes for the second `ComboBox`. Where is the collection of possible values for `TheatreID`?

Comment: MovieSystemLocationConverter is responsible for taking int value from enum , so that selected item works. I have tried and its working fine and displaying also all location enum values.
Two combobox should display location and theatre ids, dynamically if possible.

Comment: ReleasedMovies  is colleciton for theatre ids

Comment: Is your question only about binding the first `ComboBox`es `ItemSource` to the `Locations` property? What about all the question marks in the bindings?

Comment: There is no separate collection Location, enum is the only source of data. And I created one Observable collection Locations to try with which also we can take as an collection for Location combobox.
Yes I want to display enum values only. LocationViewModel contains one property with Enum location as data type.

TheatreID's collection supposed to be inside ReleasedMovies in MovieSystem class.
We can ignore Theatre id combo box as of now as if Location combobox is able to display dynamically, second one also will do eventually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242509/discussion-between-thatguy-and-user3165200).

Comment: https://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is since you are binding `Items.Control` with a collection, child elements of that `Items.Control` will have access to that collection's property only. So, if you want to use another collection you need to use `relative source` to get access in `datacontext` level. And since it's an `enum` to properly display, you need to display the dictionary values using an extension method and also using another `Itemtemplate` inside `ComboBox` to get the proper display.

```
internal class MovieSystemPanelViewModel
{
        ///Use  dictionary instead of observable collection
        public Dictionary<TheatreLocation , string> Locations { get; } = new Dictionary<TheatreLocation , string>();
   
        public MovieSystem MovieSystem { get; };
              
        public MovieSystemPanelViewModel() 
        {
            // Fill up data in dictionary
            foreach (Enum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TheatreLocation)))
            {
                Locations.Add((TheatreLocation)item, ((TheatreLocation)item).GetDisplayName());
            }
        }
}
```

Write a Extension method  in project somewhere, for display member according to requirement.

```
public static string GetDisplayName(this TheatreLocation location)
{
            switch (location)
            {
                case TheatreLocation.CityCentre:
                    return "Center city location";

                case TheatreLocation.CityNorth :
                    return "Northern city location";

                case TheatreLocation.CitySouth :
                    return "Southern city location";

                case TheatreLocation.CityEast :
                    return "Eastern city location";

                case CameraLocation.CityWest :
                    return "Western city location";

                 default:
                    return "Unknown";
            }
}
```

Now Bind `xaml` with these properties and methods.

```
<ComboBox 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path= DataContext.Locations, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Path =Location , Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource MovieSystemLocationConverter}}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                   </DataTemplate>
              </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```